# Probability of success of iterated process?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a random trial that either succeeds or fails.

Let $P_n$ be the probability that the $n$th trial succeeds and $X_i$ be the indicator variable that the $i$th trial succeeds.

$P_2 = 0.5$ and
$P_n = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum^{n-1}_{1}X_i$

That is, the probability of success for the $n$th trial is the average rate of success over the past $n-1$ trials.

How do I calculate $P_n$? Is it possible without considering all $2^n$ outcomes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process is actually simpler then you might think:

If the first trial succeeds, the second trial has a $100\%$ chance of succeeding, and all following trials too.

If the first trial fails, the second trial has a $0\%$ chance of succeeding, and all following trials too.

Therefore $P_n=0.5$ for all $n$. (And furthermore, all $X_i$ have a correlation of $1$ with each other, they are actually identical)

EDIT: answer to your more general question: If you set $P_1=P_2=...=P_k=0.5$ and $P_n=\frac{1}{1-n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_i$ for $n>k$ for some fixed $k$, then the $X_i$ will no longer be identical. But still, $P_n=0.5$ for all $n$. This is easiest to see by symmetry: Exchanging the words "success" and "failure" does not change anything (i.e. $0.5$ success-rate is the same as $0.5$ failure rate), therefore the solution must be symmetric as well.

Comment: Ah! I realized my mistake. Suppose we only define $P_2 = 0.5$. Is there a solution?

Comment: and then what is $P_1$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to define it, but we can assume that the first two trials are one success and one failure?

Comment: you can simply say $P_1=P_2=0.5$ and use the formula for $P_3$ and following. I edited my answer.